# How to unarchive a symbolic link from a .7z file, keeping it as symbolic link?

Tags: java, 7zip

Trying to write java code to extract .7z file in Linux. My .7z file contains symbolic link, but after extraction symbolic links are converted to text files.
How can I extract symbolic link from a .7z file, keeping it as symbolic link?
Tried 2 different approach, none of them working.

```
1.    MyRandomAccessFile istream = new MyRandomAccessFile(<path-to-7z-file>, "r");
IInArchive archive = new Handler();
archive.Open(istream);
ArchiveExtractCallback extractCallbackSpec = new ArchiveExtractCallback();
extractCallbackSpec.setOutFilePath(<o/p path>);
IArchiveExtractCallback extractCallback = extractCallbackSpec;
extractCallbackSpec.Init(archive);
archive.Extract(null, -1, IInArchive.NExtract_NAskMode_kExtract, extractCallback);

2.    SevenZFile sevenZFile = new SevenZFile(new File(<path-to-7z-file>));
SevenZArchiveEntry entry;
while ((entry = sevenZFile.getNextEntry()) != null) {
if (entry.isDirectory()) {
 continue;
}
File curfile = new File(<o/p path>, entry.getName());
File parent = curfile.getParentFile();
if (!parent.exists()) {
parent.mkdirs();
}
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(curfile);
byte[] content = new byte[(int) entry.getSize()];
sevenZFile.read(content, 0, content.length);
out.write(content);
out.close();
```

Comment: The best way to describe code is to show it. I hope you appreciate the difficulty in fixing code that we can not see.

Comment: For the first code snippet, I couldn't find documentation in the SDK, so can't help. For the second snippet, you are obviously creating a new file - you can't create a symbolic link using FileOutputStream.write(). A stupid question: does the 7z command line executable create a symbolic link?

Comment: check this: https://superuser.com/questions/128969/symbolic-links-and-7zip